# Find and Replace every 2nd line in a pair under certain conditions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm looking to replace multiple lines (thousands) using the following example in Notepad++:

```
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\West\comporgel.zip</ApplicationPath>
<CommandLine />
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\West\Christmas.zip</ApplicationPath>
<Photo />
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\West\spruce1.zip</ApplicationPath>
<CommandLine />
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\East\spruce1.zip</ApplicationPath>
<CommandLine />
```

Where I need to search for all  lines that contain the subfolder `\West\` and replace the line immediately following it only if it matches `<CommandLine />` with `<CommandLine>trees -nowindow</CommandLine>`

The output should look like this:

```
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\West\comporgel.zip</ApplicationPath>
<CommandLine>trees -nowindow</CommandLine>
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Confiers\North America\West\Christmas.zip</ApplicationPath>
<Photo />
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\West\spruce.zip</ApplicationPath>
<CommandLine>trees -nowindow</CommandLine>
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\East\spruce1.zip</ApplicationPath>
<CommandLine />
```

All I know to do is go to Search -> replace but I don't know how to find this:

```
<ApplicationPath>F:\Objects\Trees\Conifers\North America\West\RANDOMTEXT.zip</ApplicationPath>
<CommandLine />
```

and replace only the commandline section with `<CommandLine>trees -nowindow</CommandLine>`.

Comment: This sounds like something you should do in a script, not Notepad.

Comment: Why was this question closed because it "needed focus"  FOUR DAYS after it was answered? The question is quite focused on one specific scenario and BOTH answers received addressed it with precisely the information needed.

Comment: "needs focus" is the generic close reason when the question contains no attempt to solve the problem itself.

Comment: Well that's the point, not knowing how means no attempt COULD be made other than using regular searching, which was fairly self evident, or so I thought.

Comment: We don't write code for you. We expect you to try to solve the problem yourself, and post your best attempt. Then we'll help you fix it. This is programming, not paint-by-numbers, you're expected to be able to create original code without having to search for it.

Comment: What part of not knowing that code was involved in solving this problem is hard to understand? I updated with my initial attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the search to Regular expression mode:

[image: Notepad++ search box showing this search]

Find what: `^(<ApplicationPath>[^<]*?\\West\\[^<]+?</ApplicationPath>\r?\n)<CommandLine />`

Replace with: `\1<CommandLine>trees -nowindow</CommandLine>`

Comment: I have no idea why but Notepad++ keeps telling me that it can't find the text

Comment: Figured it out, there are spaces in from of <AplicationPath> and <CommandLine> that weren't accounted for

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are using something like Notepad++, which supports full regex replacements, you may try the following:

```regex
Find:    (<ApplicationPath>.*\\West\\.*<\/ApplicationPath>\n)<CommandLine \/>
Replace: $1<CommandLine>trees -nowindow</CommandLine>
```

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/LCQ7ci/1).

Comment: The demo works but in Notepad++ it cant find the any matches

Comment: Use regex mode when you do the search.

Comment: It wasn't that. There were spaces that weren't being accounted for